# viewForHeaderInSection not called on tableview reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 view controllers A and B, view for viewForHeaderInSection is loading properly first time, I have a segue to connect to View B, when I click Back button on navigation bar from view B, View A loads, but if I click on section header its crashing. upon debugging I noticed, viewForHeaderInSection is not called on reload.

I added self.tableView.delegate = self to onViewDidLoad() function, it doesn't seem to work, I have heightForHeaderInSection properly defined.

Why it is not being called on reload only? help please.

Comment: When you navigate back in a uinavigation controller, the destination (A) isn't reloaded, the view controller that is already in memory is simply displayed. You will get a call to `viewWill/DidAppear` but not to `viewDidLoad`. What crash do you get?

Comment: Thank you for making that clear, I added code in viewWillAppear related to sections and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This method only works correctly when tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:) is also implemented. (From documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewDidAppear` to reload what's necessary instead, cause if you hit back, the view is presented from heap memory.

Hope it helps